# NullPointerException when selecting DataSource in MultiTenant Connection Provider

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, multi-tenant

I repurposed an existing hibernate-spring project and upgraded to Hibernate 4 and Spring 4 and added multiple datasources using multitenancy. The application starts fine, the datasources are being read in using the MultiTenantDataSourceLookup class. When setting the new tenant, the tenant is resolved but then I get the nullpointerexception on line 41 of MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl(See comment for line). I'm also using GenericHibernateDAO if that helps. I can post that code by request. I'm new to spring so the problem may be a very simple one. However, if more code is needed to help me, I will be happy to share more as I troubleshoot and research the problem myself. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks. Here is the full stack trace: http://pastebin.com/LjyhTwvY

---

**MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.java**

```
public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl extends AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl
{

    @Autowired
    private DataSource defaultDataSource;
    @Autowired
    private DataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup;

    /**
     * Select datasources in situations where not tenantId is used (e.g.    startup processing).
     */
    @Override
    protected DataSource selectAnyDataSource() {
        return defaultDataSource;
    }

    /**
     * Obtains a DataSource based on tenantId
     */
    @Override
    protected DataSource selectDataSource(String tenantIdentifier) {
        //Below is line 41 where the nullpointerexeption is occurring
        DataSource ds = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(tenantIdentifier);
        return ds;
    }   
}
```

---

**CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl.java**

```
public class CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

    private static final String KEY_TENANTID_SESSION = "hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_TENANTID = "customer1";


    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {

        String tenant = resolveTenantByHttpSession();       
        System.out.println("Tenant resolved: " + tenant);
        return tenant;
    }


    /**
     * Get tenantId in the session attribute KEY_TENANTID_SESSION
     * @return TenantId on KEY_TENANTID_SESSION
     */
    public String resolveTenantByHttpSession()
    {
        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        //If session attribute exists returns tenantId saved on the session
        if(attr != null){
            HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession(false); // true == allow create
            if(session != null){
                String tenant = (String) session.getAttribute(KEY_TENANTID_SESSION);
                if(tenant != null){
                    return tenant;
                }
            }
        }
        //otherwise return default tenant
        return DEFAULT_TENANTID;
    }


    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

**Context.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />

<bean id="multitenancyConnectionProvider"
   class="com.github.elizabetht.util.MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl"/>
<bean id="dataSourceLookup"
   class="com.github.elizabetht.util.MultiTenantDataSourceLookup"/>
<bean id="tenantResolver"
   class="com.github.elizabetht.util.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl"/>


<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.github.elizabetht.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>        
        <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.multiTenancy">DATABASE</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider">com.github.elizabetht.util.MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver">com.github.elizabetht.util.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>   

<bean id="defaultDataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentEnrollment" />
    <property name="username" value="springy" />
    <property name="password" value="pass" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  <property name="autodetectDataSource" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
Tenant resolved: customer1

Feb 25, 2017 1:34:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [studentHibernateServlet] in context with path [/StudentEnrollmentWithSpring] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.github.elizabetht.util.MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.selectDataSource(MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.java:41)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.java:52)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$ContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:423)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
```

Comment: Clearly `dataSourceLookup` is null, and with the configuration given, I'd guess that Hibernate has instantiated its own instance of `MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl` instead of getting it injected through Spring.

Comment: Deleted last comment because I was mistaken, sorry about that. I see what your saying, trying to fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my hibernate properties to the following and everything works now:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <map> 
        <entry key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider" value-ref="multitenancyConnectionProvider"/> 
        <entry key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value-ref="tenantResolver"/>                               
        <entry key="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="DATABASE"/> 
    </map> 
</property>
```